# Pika: How to have a ideal connection between producer and broker?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, keep-alive, pika

## Source of the problem

My twisted have to publish message to rabbitmq from time to time. But in the process of testing it, the following questions have emerged:

1. `ConnectionClosed: Broken pipe`
2. `ConnectionClosed: timeout`
3. `ConnectionClosed: (-1, "ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')")`
4. `ChannelClosed`

## Requirements

This connection needs to meet the following requirements:

1. Will not be disconnected.
2. Can be **automatically** reconnected when disconnected.

## Calling code

```
mq = MessageQueue()
mq.declare_direct_exchange("exchange")
mq.publish_message(message)
```

## MessageQueue Class

I set channel to a class attributes cause later created mq instance do not have to re-create a connection.

```
class MessageQueue():
channel = None

def __init__(self):
    if not MessageQueue.channel:
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("name", "password")
        conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(ip,
                                                credentials = credentials,
                                                heartbeat=10)
        conn_broker = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)

        MessageQueue.channel = conn_broker.channel()

    self.exchange_declared = False
    self.exchange_name = ""

def declare_direct_exchange(self, exchange_name):
    self.exchange_name = exchange_name
    self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name,
                                  exchange_type="direct",
                                  passive=False,
                                  durable=True,
                                  auto_delete=False)
    self.exchange_declared = True

def publish_message(self, message=""):
    if not self.exchange_declared:
        raise ExchangeNotDeclaredException("Exchange must be declared "
                                           "before publish messages.")
    msg_props = pika.BasicProperties()
    msg_props.content_type = "text/plain"

    self.channel.basic_publish(body=message,
                               exchange=self.exchange_name,
                               properties=msg_props,
                               routing_key="hola")
```